# hash in JS == hash in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, hash

I need to make a hash with JS and PHP but I need them to both work out to be the same hash.
I am just wondering what the best idea would be to go about it. it needs to be secure, but its not hashing sensitive data so doesn't need a huge amount of security around it.

could anyone give me some examples

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you talking about a cryptographic hash / digest like SHA / MD5 or about a hashmap structure?

Comment: you mention hashing and encrypting in the same question, these are quite different things, which do you want to do?

Comment: @Phil was thinking more along the lines of SHA / MD5

Comment: @Elgoog Thanks, it was the "value and key" reference that threw me

Comment: @Phil sorry for not making it clear enough and also for the 'value/key' ref

Comment: A **big** word of warning from personal experience if you go with MD5: JavaScript is always UTF8, and PHP isn't.  Therefore, if you are dealing with UTF8 characters, you may get different results for what *appears* to be the same input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use MD5: the php and the JS solution should work out to be the same given the same string input. http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/ has a list of hash implementations in javascript, and PHP implementations of md5 are documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), and both have examples at hand.

You'll need to be careful that you use the exact same input to both functions, but otherwise it shouldn't be too painful.

Answer (score 2):

### A more modern approach

In [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), use:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', "here_is_my_input_string");
```

Then in JavaScript you can use the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest):

```js
function hashAsync(algo, str) {
  return crypto.subtle.digest(algo, new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(str)).then(buf => {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buf), x=>(('00'+x.toString(16)).slice(-2))).join('');
  });
}

hashAsync("SHA-256", "here_is_my_input_string").then(outputHash => console.log(outputHash));
// prints: 4bb047046382f9c2aeb32ae6d2e43439f05d11bd74658f1d160755ff48114364 which also matches 3rd party site: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926440/470749

Answer (score 1):

Well don't forget that javascript is inherently insecure because it is client side, but if you're hashing for communication with say ajax, or you don't want to spend the money on a ssl certificate, then this could be the way to go.

The most common hashing algorithms are md5 and sha256.  Now, because these are algorithms they don't need to be coded into the language (as they are in php), but can written with the language.  Some very smart people have already done the hard work for you, and now you just need to get their source.

MD5:    http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html
SHA256: http://www.bichlmeier.info/sha256.html