# String hashing function that would produce identical results in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, hash

I'd like to know is there a string hashing function that would produce identical results both in JavaScript and PHP, just to avoid text transmissions in cases when some textual data coming from the client side needs to be verified on the server side for being the same as expected?

Comment: Here is an earlier related question that this one might be a duplicate of: [hash in JS == hash in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991401/hash-in-js-hash-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, See this [md5](http://phpjs.org/functions/md5:469) hashing function for JS. Here is [sha1](http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1:512).

You'd find more in http://PHPjs.org

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of string hashing algorithms you can select from.  Google will give you lots of choices.  One popular algorithm is MD5 which I'm sure you can find implementations for in both javascript and PHP.  Here's [one reference](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/) on MD5 with javascript code and here's a [second reference](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html) for javascript.

MD5 has the characteristic you are seeking that the same string always produces the same hash value and it can be implemented in any language.

I don't know PHP myself, but it appears that PHP might already have a function called `md5()` built in.  See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MD5 hashing, you will get the same result in both javascript and PHP

[PHP MD5 Hash](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

[JQuery MD5 plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/md5)

or [Without JQuery MD5 function](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html)