# How do I hash a string using JavaScript with sha512 algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, server-side

I've tried using sha512 from NPM but it keeps hashing the wrong thing i.e I am supposed to get a string but it keeps returning object.
So in PHP I know I can perform the task `$hash = hash("sha512","my string for hashing");`

How do I perform this task on nodejs JavaScript

Comment: Most browsers have a Crypto API and [there's a SHA256 demo](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/10/30/web-cryptography-api-hello-world/) If you want to use a third-party library, you need to specify which library you used.

Comment: sha512 github page says `This library is deprecated.` While browsing npm atleast check if it's actively maintained. https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/sha512

Comment: Yes I remembered I logged this deprecation error earlier and I was wondering why because I've tried different libraries on NPM. I'll try cryptocoinjs out.

Comment: @Lewis Apologies for the accusation! 

Yes it's a warning that breaks the API. The code literally stops running at that point and won't return anything. I'll have to make changes and restart the server to make it work again. Again I'm sorry for accusing you wrongly.

Comment: @Lewis thanks!

I'll do the same

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you are using Node:

```
> crypto.createHash('sha512').update('my string for hashing').digest('hex');
'4dc43467fe9140f217821252f94be94e49f963eed1889bceab83a1c36ffe3efe87334510605a9bf3b644626ac0cd0827a980b698efbc1bde75b537172ab8dbd0'
```

If you want to use the browser Web Crypto API:

```
function sha512(str) {
  return crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-512", new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(str)).then(buf => {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buf), x=>(('00'+x.toString(16)).slice(-2))).join('');
  });
}

sha512("my string for hashing").then(x => console.log(x));
// prints: 4dc43467fe9140f217821252f94be94e49f963eed1889bceab83a1c36ffe3efe87334510605a9bf3b644626ac0cd0827a980b698efbc1bde75b537172ab8dbd0
```

Comment: why does it say sha256, when OP asked for sha512?

Comment: @BlueRineS Edited.

Comment: Note: Chrome thinks that you do not deserve to use hashing functions if you can't make yourself an SSL certificate for things running over your intranet. https://w3.org/2016/08/29-crypto-minutes.html

Comment: In the `map` function call, do we really need to do `('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)`? Wouldn't `slice(-2)`, return the same result irrespectively?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this library [npm.io/package/js-sha512](https://npm.io/package/js-sha512)

```
npm install js-sha512
```

- exemple:

```js
import {sha512} from "js-sha512";

let str = "hello"
let secretKey = "MYSECRETKEY"

let hash = sha512.hmac(secretKey, str);
```

Note: sha512 is a One-way compression function
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32641843)